# Invalid Syntax in a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Here is the code:

```
...

T=[]
To=1
for 'To' <= 10000:
    T.append(To)
    To=To+0.25
...
```

And the error is:

```
    for 'To' <= 10000:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why this can't be run. Is the symbol "<=" wrong?
I checked the indentations and read almost all the questions on this website about similar errors, but I do not see where my error is.

Answer (score 2):

'To' is a character string, and the `for` statement makes no sense.

`To` is a variable name.  Don't confuse them.  You need

```
while To <= 10000:
    ....
```

Better yet, drop the increment statement at the bottom of the loop, and use the `for` properly, adjusting the values for your needs:

```
for To in range(10000):
```

---

Also, please use descriptive variable names; `To` and `Xo` don't tell us anything, and `To` is readily confused with a reserved word in many languages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to create an array of numbers, starting at 1 and increasing by .25 each time, until the final value is 10000.

If that's the case, NumPy will do this for you ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)):

```
T = np.arange(1.0, 10000, .25)
```